# XMl Namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, namespaces

I need to obtain a SAML assertion from an external source, and then pass it directly into the wsse:Security header of an outgoing WCF/SOAP message.  I **don't** wish to parse, verify or do anything else with it - just treat it as an XML "blob".

I can almost do this by creating a new MessageHader object like this:

```
MessageHeader h = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", 
"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", 
MyXmlBlob);
```

BUT it then uses the security namespace quoted in that line as the "default" namespace - i.e. it doesn't use a an alias/prefix, and this causes problems for my blob, as that was written (by others outside my control!) with a specific prefix (wsse: in this case) for that namespace.

I've searched and experimented with all sorts of variations, but so far I've failed to find any way to persuade Createheader to use a prefix - does anyone know if any such means exists?  I know that I could manipulate the blob to add a new xmlns definition at that level, but I'd prefer to avoid potential problems and leave it "untouched" if possible.

Comment: Can you add more code examples (your XML source, or *all* the relevant parts), the outcome you need and some of the variations you tried (code)?